# R: creating a im object from a function to be the covariate of my model

Tags: r, spatstat

I want to create a im object from a function that assign a value according to the distance with respect to a fixed line, i.e. if the point is away from the line its value is near zero and opposite if this is near to the line. I have created the following functions:

```
library(spatstat)

W <- owin(xrange = c(-0.5, 4.5), yrange = c(-0.5, 3.5))

covValue <- function(x, y) {
  # defining the segment AB
  b <- W$yrange[2] + 2
  A <- c(W$xrange[1], b)
  I <- c(W$xrange[2], W$yrange[2])
  m <- (I[2] - A[2]) / (I[1] - A[1])
  B <- c((W$yrange[1] - b) / m, 0)

  C <- c(x, y)

  C <- c(4.5, 3.5)
  x1 <- A[1]
  y1 <- A[2]
  x2 <- B[1]
  y2 <- B[2]
  x3 <- C[1]
  y3 <- C[2]

  # calculating the orthogonal point D that belongs to the segment AB with respect to a given point C = (x,y) inside the observation window

  px  <- x2 - x1
  py  <- y2 - y1
  dAB <- px * px + py * py
  u   <- ((x3 - x1) * px + (y3 - y1) * py) / dAB
  xr   <- x1 + u * px
  yr   <- y1 + u * py

  D <- c(xr, yr)
  # t<-((C[1]-A[1])*(B[1]-A[1])+(C[2]-A[2])*(B[2]-A[2]))/((B[1]-A[1])^2+(B[2]-A[2])^2)
  # Dx=A[1]+t*(B[1]-A[1])
  # Dy=A[2]+t*(B[2]-A[2])

  # if the point C is away from the segment AB, this has less value
  dist  <- sqrt((C[1] - D[1]) ^ 2 + (C[2] - D[2]) ^ 2)
  value <- 1 / exp(dist)
  return(value)
}
```

The function works fine, now I try to create the im object:

```
imagen <- as.im(covValue, W = W)
```

I get this error:

> Error: length(mat) == length(xcol) * length(yrow) is not TRUE

Can someone please help me, thanks.

Comment: Not familiar with this package, but try something like this: `imagen <- as.im(covValue(1, 1), W = W)`.

Comment: Also, I cannot see where in the function arguments `x` and `y` are used...

Comment: @Samuel : I am using as template this example from the book of the spatstat package: f <- function(x,y){15*(cos(sqrt((x-3)^2+3*(y-3)^2)))^2} > A <- as.im(f, W=square(6))

Answer (score 0):

Function must be vectorised such that for vectors x and y of length n it must return a vector of length n. If you just need the distance to the line segment you can create a psp object and use distfun on that. In airport now so I can't  fill in the details.